# Изменение многомерного массива js

Tags: javascript, массивы

> Создайте двумерный массив из элементов 5x5 и заполните его произвольными целыми значениями. На главной диагонали замените все числа со знаком (-) на 10, а числа со знаком (+) на цифру 20.

Почему-то в результате получаю массив из `undefined`. Помогите разобраться, где ошибка?

```
let matrix = [
    [-1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [12, 34, 1, 2, 3],
    [45, 23, -4, 2, 6],
    [3, 35, 76, 545, 5],
    [45, 5, 65, 4, -24]
];



console.log(matrix.map(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                if (matrix[i] < 0) {
                    matrix[i] = 10;
                } else {
                    matrix[i] =20;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: уберите `map` из этого кода

Comment: Поняла ошибку. Но функция к массиву не применяется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let matrix = [
    [-1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [12, 34, 1, 2, 3],
    [45, 23, -4, 2, 6],
    [3, 35, 76, 545, 5],
    [45, 5, 65, 4, -24]
];

for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            if (matrix[i][j] < 0) {
                matrix[i][j] = 10;
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = 20;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log (matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let matrix = [
  [-1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [12, 34, 1, 2, 3],
  [45, 23, -4, 2, 6],
  [3, 35, 76, 545, 5],
  [45, 5, 65, 4, -24],
];

const res = matrix.map((row, y) =>
  row.map((item, x) => (y === x ? (item < 0 ? 10 : 20) : item))
);
console.log("res", res);
```